# ¿Cómo acceder a una propiedad boolena en una colección de objetos?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función en la cual como argumento se ingresa un objeto A, y dentro de este hay otros tres objetos y dentro de cada objeto hay una propiedad booleana en la cual una dice true y las otras dicen false. ¿Cómo puedo acceder solo a la que dice true? Investigue y vi que era con el método `for .. in` pero no logro comprender.

```
function vegan(invitados) {

  // let invitados = {
  //     Luna: {
  //         vegan: false
  //     },
  //     Sebas: {
  //         vegan: false
  //     },
  //     Marce: {
  //         vegan: false
  //     },
  //     Nicky: {
  //         vegan: true
  //     }
  // };
 
  // mi código aca:

  for (const vegan in invitados){
    if ((invitados[vegan]) === true){
      return invitados;
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Buenas noches, ¿Qué haz intentado?.

Comment: digamos que use el metodo for in , ingrese (invitado[asistencia]) para acceder a la propiedad, pero mas alla no se que mas hacer, ya que necesito retornar solo lo que dicen true

Comment: Muéstranos tu código por favor y coméntanos el inconveniente que tengas. Edita tu pregunta y añade esos detalles.

Comment: Listo ya lo modifique

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución por ahí no es tan sencilla si sos más o menos nueva en JS, pero usa algunos métodos de **Object** interesantes y te pueden servir para enriquecer tu conocimiento del lenguaje, lo bueno es que si hay más de una persona con `vegan=true` lo agrega al resultado, y se conserva la misma estructura que tenes dentro de "invitados":

```
function getVegan(invitados){ // la funcion devolvera la persona cuyo propiedad vegan sea true
  let result = {}; // variable auxiliar tipo objecto
  Object.entries(invitados).forEach((element) => { // usamos Object.entries y recorremos el array que devuelve con forEach, element a su vez es un array con el nombre del objeto (la persona), y otro con el objeto {vegan: true/false}
    if(element[1].vegan==true) result = Object.defineProperty(result, element[0], {value: {vegan: true}})
    // si vegan es true para el element actual definimos una nueva propiedad a la variable auxiliar,
    // el nombre de dicha propiedad sera el nombre de la persona cuyo vegan sea verdadero, y su valor sera un objeto { vegan: true/false } (igual que como tenias originalmente en invitados)
  })
  return result; // devolvemos variable objeto auxiliar
}

console.log(getVegan(invitados))
```

ya tenes una respuesta valida pero te queria compartir la mia por si te servia, saludos

Answer (score 0):

##### Explicación:

Cuando recorres el objeto, tienes que ingresar a los elementos de los objetos, en este caso son `Luna`, `Sebas`, `Marce` y `Nicky`. Para ingresar a sus elementos con el [**`for...in`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), se hace de la siguiente forma:

```js
for (var personas in invitados) {
  console.log(invitados[personas]);
}
```

En donde te retorna lo siguiente:

```js
// {vegan: false}
// {vegan: false}
// {vegan: false}
// {vegan: true}
```

Y ya con estos resultados iremos evaluando si es **`true`** o **`false`**,  sería de la siguiente manera:

```js
if (invitados[personas].vegan) // si de los elementos ingresados, "vegan" es true...
```

---

##### Código final:

```js
let invitados = {
  Luna: {
    vegan: false,
  },
  Sebas: {
    vegan: false,
  },
  Marce: {
    vegan: false,
  },
  Nicky: {
    vegan: true,
  },
};

function vegan(invitados) {
  for (var personas in invitados) {
    if (invitados[personas].vegan)
      return personas + ' -> ' + invitados[personas].vegan;
  }
}

console.log(vegan(invitados));
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de nuevo con el siguiente código, para acceder a la propiedad "vegan" antes recuerda que debes acceder a la propiedad de los nombres que tienes definidos

Accederias de la siguiente forma a la propiedad vegan

- Invitados > Luna > vegan

Invitados[Luna].vegan

```
let invitados = {
       Luna: {
           vegan: false
       },
       Sebas: {
           vegan: false
       },
       Marce: {
           vegan: false
       },
       Nicky: {
           vegan: true
       }
   };

function vegan(objInvitados)
{
      for(let name in objInvitados)
        {
          if(objInvitados[name].vegan)
            {
              return console.log(name+' is vegan');
            }
        }
}

vegan(invitados);
```